# How far away would the moon need to be to not be visible anymore?

Tags: science-based, space

If the moon were three times the distance from Earth would it still be visible?

I mean: **how far away would it need to be to fade out into the darkness of space?**

My guess is that it would no longer be able to be seen during the day if it were three times the distance from Earth it is today. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Jamie*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: What's your actual question? Three times, or how far? What's your definition of "visible"? Because Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter and Saturn can be seen with naked eye.

Comment: and those look more like stars....due to their size. i cant help but notice the dark round areas in the sky during the day lightly shaded from the natural color of the sky. even clouds arent illuminating in these darker areas in the sky when the sun is close enough to light them up.  ....but if the moon were 3x the distance from earth would it still be visible in the day? its barely visible now ...

Comment: The moon will never be far enough away to be completely invisible unless it was behind something else. If you want it far enough away to where its little more than a speck in the sky, lets go ahead and say .75 AU. At that range it'll probably look like a tiny star on a good night and it'll probably be considered its own planet and not our moon. The moon appears less visible during the day for various reasons and distance isn't one of them.

Comment: if that were true about the distance then the entire moon would be visible in the daytime no?

Comment: Mercury is not that much larger than the Moon, you know...

Comment: If the moon was 3x as far away, it'd be about 1/3 the size, but still with the same surface brightness - that's determined by how far from the sun it is, and the shift is a tiny fraction of the sun-moon distance. And we do see the entire *lit* section of the moon that's facing towards us in the daytime.

Comment: I know very little about cosmology, but if I'm not mistaken, the moon only reflects light, it does not produce it.  Since light travels minimally disturbed in a vacuum, any light that hits it will be reflected extremely long distances.  However if it was no longer reflecting light it wouldn't be visible.

Comment: @Mołot: Yes, so "far away" depends on whether it's closer to the Sun, like Mercury, or further away, like Mars.  Also we don't often see Mercury at night (in complete darkness), only during the twilight at sunrise or sunset.

Comment: @jamesqf I know. I'm only asking OP to define what he considers "visible".

Comment: Would it not be enough to be _still visible_, but of the size and brightness of stars (in Ancient Greek sense), so the relative size of Mars or Venus on our skies would probably suffice to classify it as a yet another planet, but not as a moon. Relative brightness of our Moon is -12.7, of Sun – -26.7, of Venus – -4.6. Notice the scale is logarithmic.

Comment: [Space 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_1999) should have the answer.

Comment: The moon would have to be about 6 times further away for a person with 20/20 vision to be unable to discern it. It would still technically be visible, just really blurry and hard to see. For it to be completely invisible you would have to move it a lot further away.

Answer (score 9):

## Three times isn't far enough

**tldr;**

**- Three time further away is magnitude -10.5 (brighter than [Comet Ikeya–Seki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Ikeya%E2%80%93Seki) which was visible by day)**

**- If the moon was further than 60.3 times further away it wouldn't be visible by day (and also wouldn't be orbiting Earth)**

The light reaching us would be reduced with the inverse square law, assuming the moon is still orbiting Earth the amount of sunlight hitting it should be roughly the same and the intensity then reduced to a ninth that of the current day.
$$r=\frac{r_{0}}{3}$$
$$I=\frac{I_{0}}{3^{2}}=\frac{I_{0}}{9}$$

- In its current position [the Moon has an apparent magnitude of -12.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude#Table_of_notable_celestial_objects)
- [An apparent magnitude of -4 or less is needed to be visible in the daytime sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude#Table_of_notable_celestial_objects)
- Apparent magnitude [can be calculated by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(astronomy)#Apparent_magnitude):
  $$m_{1}-m_{ref} = -2.5 \log_{10}\frac{I_{1}}{I_{ref}}$$
  So lets take $m_{1}$ as our new magnitude (for the moon three times further away) and $I_{1}$ is then the intensity of light from the moon in its new position but $I_{ref}$ is the current position of the moon and $m_{ref}$ is the current magnitude.
  $$m_{ref} = -12.9$$
  $$\frac{I_{1}}{I_{ref}} = \frac{1}{9}$$
  So:
  $$m_{1} = -12.9 - 2.5 \log_{10}\frac{1}{9} = -10.5...$$

So your moon would still be well in the visible range. Rearranging our equation and taking $\frac{I_{1}}{I_{ref}}$ as a ratio of distances squared from earth we get $\frac{r_{new}^{2}}{r_{old}^{2}}$ or $\frac{1}{N^{2}}$ where $N$ is the number of times further away our new moon is. Now take -4 as its apparent magnitude:
$$10^{\frac{-4 +12.9}{2.5}} = N^{2} = 3631$$
$$N = \sqrt{3631} = 60.257...$$

So the moon has to be 60 times further away, thats $384,400 km \times 60 =  23,064,000 km$. Thats nearly half way to mars (56 million km) at closest approach, it would be unlikely that the moon would still be *our* moon for long. In fact, [as bendl pointed out](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101136/how-far-away-would-the-moon-need-to-be-to-not-be-visible-anymore#comment303842_101153), this is well outside the Earth's Hill sphere and so a stable orbit cannot exist.

This would still be visible at night, however. There are several limits to choose from in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude#Table_of_notable_celestial_objects) scale, naked eye standard dark skies, naked eye darkest skies, binocular....etc. Just enter them into the equation:

$$N = \sqrt{10^{\frac{M+12.9}{2.5}} }$$

Where the $M$ is the magnitude of your choice.

Comment: The Hill Sphere for Earth is ~1.5 million km, so it wouldn't be our moon at all.

Answer (score 2):

If the moon were three times further away it would still be visible in daylight under some conditions such as morning and evening times. It would still be visible as a disc although a very small one.

For the moon to be invisible to the naked eye it would have to be tens of millions of miles away. The planet Mercury is visible to the naked eye under the right conditions and is not that much larger than the moon.

A moon of earth cannot have an orbit of tens of millions of miles as this would be gravitationally unstable. Such an orbit would be very rapidly distorted by the influence of the sun and inner solar system planets and the moon would probably end up in orbit around the sun rather than the earth.

Comment: Heck, the moon is *already* trying to leave Earth orbit (it gets farther away every year by some minuscule fraction I can't be bothered to look up)

Comment: For sure it is, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Oh I know it wasn't. :)

Answer (score 1):

By the time the Moon is far enough away to be invisible to the naked eye, it wouldn't be orbiting the Earth anymore. *That could also be exciting, though :)*

Brightness reduces with the inverse square of distance, and [brightness magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(astronomy)) (wiki link: see the 'Examples' table) is measured on a special log scale. Put together, we get:

r/r0 = 2.5^(BrightnessMagnitudeChange/2)

where r/r0 is the relative increase in distance. As an example, if it's 2, that would mean the Moon would be twice as far away as it is now. Calculating

Full Moon invisible at day
r/r0 = 61 times farther away = 2.5^((-4--13)/2)

Full Moon invisible at night
r/r0 = 6031 times farther away = 2.5^((6--13)/2)

The Moon would start to get dragged away from Earth by Solar gravity at an r/r0 of about (roughly) 2.5, which doesn't allow for a huge amount of change in brightness. Search 'Earth SOI' for more. The r/r0 of 61 (invisible at day) puts the Moon about a third of the way to Mars. At this point the distance to the sun would start to dim it as well. Meanwhile that 6031 value for invisible at night is right out there!

But of course you could always change its albedo (**Paint it Black!**)

Comment: Love the paint job idea.